# Custom Button (javascript) - Field Name Changes Are Not Automatically Made

Tags: javascript, custom-button, administration, button

I understand generally WHY this happens, but I'm curious if there is a **better way to write the two references in code below** so that if I RENAME the FIELD in SF, it updates the code?

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT ("/soap/ajax/13.0/connection.js")} 

var formid = "{!Company_Form_Opp__c.Id}"; 
var userid = "{!$User.Id}"; 
var FormToUpdate = new sforce.SObject("Company_Form_Opp__c"); 

var padyear = {!YEAR(TODAY())}; 
var padmonth = {!MONTH(TODAY())}; 
if( padmonth.toString().length == 1 ) { padmonth = '0'+padmonth } 
var padday = {!DAY(TODAY())}; 
if( padday.toString().length == 1 ) { padday = '0'+padday } 

if( "{!Company_Form_Opp__c.RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature__c}" != '' ) { 
alert("Already signed!"); 

} else { 

FormToUpdate.set("Id", formid); 
FormToUpdate.set( "RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature__c" , userid); 
FormToUpdate.set( "RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature_Date__c" , padyear + '-' + padmonth + '-'+ padday ); 
var Result = sforce.connection.update([FormToUpdate]); 

if(Result[0].getBoolean("success")) { 
function redirect() { parent.frames.location.replace("/{!Company_Form_Opp__c.Id}"); } 
redirect(); 
} else { 
alert("Error"); 
} 

}
```

The field reference at the "Already Signed!" IF updates itself.  The two below in **FORMTOUPDATE.SET() do not**.  What could I do to alter the FORMTOUPDATE references so that if I alter the Field name the code updates itself?

Comment: No "solution" for this at this time (2013-04-18).  Leaving question OPEN for now per suggestion received on Meta site.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit: As at April 2013, $ObjectType is not evaluated within Custom Button context. The solution below should be considered a non-starter at this time :(**

You could leverage the cached sObject describe result methods.

For example: `{!$ObjectType.Object__c.fields.Field__c.Name}` returns the field name.

Or in your case:

```
FormToUpdate.set('{!$ObjectType.Company_Form_Opp__c.fields.RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature__c.Name}', userid); 
FormToUpdate.set('{!$ObjectType.Company_Form_Opp__c.fields.RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature_Date__c.Name}', padyear + '-' + padmonth + '-'+ padday);
```

In Visualforce context, those references are coupled to the schema and will update accordingly.

Comment: Nice. I was thinking do a describe, but couldn't quite wrap my brain around how you could have it be coupled to the schema.

Comment: Sounds awesome.  Will check it out shortly.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm.  Error:    Field Company_Form_Opp__c.fields.RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature_Date__c.Name does not exist. Check spelling   (happens for both lines) (I did fix the first line where you had _Date in the var name)

Comment: @AMM can you confirm the object name works via `{!$ObjectType.Company_Form_Opp__c.Name}`?

Comment: Error: Field Company_Form_Opp__c.Name does not exist. Check spelling.

Comment: (I'm not sure how else to test that since I don't see where in the code I would use such a reference)

Comment: This reference validates for the sake of verifying:  {!Company_Form_Opp__c.RETURNFUNDS_Returned_By_Signature__c} ... but of course does not yield the name of the field

Comment: Well crap :( I guess the `$ObjectType` global is completely absent from Custom Button contents then.